# Access list of imported modules from collect_submodules in hiddenimports from PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pyinstaller

I have an application bundled using PyInstaller. One of the hooks I created added some hiddenimports from a nested package: `hiddenimports = collect_submodules("mypkg.subpkg")`. In another part of my code, at runtime I am trying to dynamically import all of the modules that are in that mypkg.subpkg so that I can iterate over the classes in each one. I was able to do this successfully using:

```
modules = [module for module in globals()['__loader__'].toc if "mypkg.subpkg" in module]
for mod_name in modules:
    imported_module = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
    for item in dir(imported_module):
        value = getattr(imported_module, item)
        if not value or not inspect.isclass(value):
            continue
```

However, that `globals()['__loader__'].toc` is not very intuitive and not documented in PyInstaller's documentation (I found it through another stack overflow post and saw it in the source code). Is there another way at runtime to access the names of the modules that were imported using hiddenimports in the PyInstaller hook?

Note: I'd like to avoid using collect_data_files because I don't want the py files in the final bundle

Comment: Note that [collect_data_files()](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_data_files) is just a function to list data files, without additional side-effects. So just by using `collect_data_files` does not add the listed files to the PyInstaller bundle, unless the return value is explicitly passed to the PyInstaller process. Basically `collect_data_files` can be called and the results filtered, without the Python scripts - returned by `collect_data_files` call - showing up in the bundle.

Comment: Hmm but how does that help once trying to actually access the classes from those modules at runtime?

Comment: So the question is how to access submodules included by hiddenimport during runtime? I am asking this because it is not clear from the current wording of the question. Is compile (build) time or runtime access required for said submodules? My assumption was that the question meant compile time access.

Comment: Sorry yes, at runtime

Comment: In that case the following should work. 1) Collect submodules in question during (or before) buildtime. 2) Store collected submodules in a descriptor (i.e. JSON) or a Python module. 3) Add descriptor or Python module created in previous step to built binary. +1 Also don't forget to edit the script where submodule list is required to use the stored collection.